# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject doesn't work with tags like this "/User"?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Is there a way to allow JsonConvert.DeserializeObject on tag names that has a "/"?

It gives a 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException'

```
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "/User")]
 public User User { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok adding this to the tag name works for me:

```
 @"\/user"

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = @"\/User")]
  public User User { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work, this is what I have tried, and this work for me.
Both serialization and deserialization works.

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new Test() { User = new User() { Name = "1234", Age = 12}};
    var js = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);

    var t = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(js);
}

public class Test {
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="/One")]
    public User User {get;set;}
}

public class User{
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Please could you be specific about what doesn't work, is it when you serialize the object into a JSON string or when attempting to deserialize a JSON string?

Comment: het, the objects that start with / are null. It seems that JsonConvert ignores all tags that start with special characters?

Comment: That isn't what I have observed. As you can see the advice code works for me. What version of json.net are you using? Try the last version.

Comment: are you sure that User returns the values "1234" and 12? or not just null?

Comment: Yes, it works . As I said earlier, I tested this code.